# Time not updating on RecyclerView using Countdown Timer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

In application have a recyclerview with multiple items and each item have own countdown timer.

Now issue is, **countdown timer running only for visible item, other remain item countdown timer running(start) only when item scroll or visible.**

I want to start all count down timer of recyclerview item. how I fix it?

Here is code:

```
class MyBidAdapter(
    private val listener: OnItemClickListener<MyBid>,
    private val userId: Int,
) :
    ListAdapter<MyBid, MyBidAdapter.MyBidViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    private val countdownTimerMap: MutableMap<Int, CountdownTimerUtil> = mutableMapOf()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyBidViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemBidBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MyBidViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyBidViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    inner class MyBidViewHolder(private val binding: ItemBidBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            binding.apply {
         }
        }

        fun bind(data: MyBid) {
            binding.apply {

                // Cancel the previous CountdownTimerUtil
                countdownTimerMap[position]?.cancel()

                val daysTextView = textView46
                val hoursTextView = textView48
                val minutesTextView = textView50
                val secondsTextView = textView52

                // Calculate total time in milliseconds
                val totalTimeInMillis: Long = data.day.toLong() * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                        data.hours.toLong() * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                        data.minute.toLong() * 60 * 1000 +
                        data.second.toLong() * 1000

                // Ensure that the CountdownTimerUtil is always initialized
                countdownTimerMap[position] = CountdownTimerUtil(
                    totalTimeInMillis, 1000,
                    daysTextView, hoursTextView, minutesTextView, secondsTextView
                ) {
                    // This code will be executed when the countdown finishes
                    button.isEnabled = false
                }
                // Start the timer
                countdownTimerMap[position]?.start()
            }
        }
    }

    class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MyBid>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MyBid, newItem: MyBid): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MyBid, newItem: MyBid): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The onBindViewHolder is invoked when the item is going to be visible, you can try to do the val totalTimeInMillis a property of the adapter, override the submitList and initialize it there. If I understood well you update the textViews accoding to the totalTimeInMillis, so if it has as initial value the timestamp of the submit it will start from there.